# In Flask how can I run another python app from subdirectory with relative path references?

Tags: python, flask

Goal is to add a standalone app (that already works on its own), call it **app1**, to my Flask build, similar to a module. The issue is the standalone app is in a subdirectory relative to where Flask is started and *main.py* can't call its own relative path resources. File structure looks like:

```
\my_flask_app\
  server.py
  \apps\
    \app1\
      main.py
      ..resources..
  \static\
  \templates\
```

I've tried **os.chdir** to change working directory before running *main.py* because updating all the paths manually would be a hassle and defeat the purpose of portability for **app1**. I'm launching app1 from a route like:

```
@app.route('/app1/run')
def app1_run():
    # launch the standalone app.
    os.chdir('apps/app1')
    import main
    return 'Clicked!'
```

This results in `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'main'`. So, I guess chdir isn't actually changing the working directory.

When I do `import apps.app1.main` instead of `import main`, this results in `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'hoverable'` (hoverable.py is a resource imported by main.py). So, that means main.py was started, but main.py couldn't locate it's relative resources.

I could go through main.py and update all the paths for resources, but that defeats the purpose a standalone module. Is there a better way to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this would be to wrap the app in the main.py file into a function, let's call it function_that_runs_the_app.  Then import that function at the top level of the file that contains your @app.route('/app1/run') view function.  At that point all you have to do is call function_that_runs_the_app with the () on the end and the code will execute before the view function returns 'Clicked!'

```
from apps.app1.main import function_that_runs_the_app

@app.route('/app1/run')
def app1_run():
    # launch the standalone app.
    success_message = function_that_runs_the_app()
    return success_message



(main.py file)
def function_that_runs_the_app():
    #  All your previous code would now go here inside the function.

    return 'Standalone app1 Ran Successfully!'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    function_that_runs_the_app()
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yeah wrapping it is cleaner, but doesn't solve the problem with referencing resources from app1. I use server.py to launch Flask. In app1, main.py calls relative resources in its own directory, not from server.py's. I can redo path references in main.py, but I'm wondering if there's a way to "plug in" app1 without needing to retool. Does that make sense?

Comment: In command line, when I go to the app1 folder, I can ```py main.py``` and the app runs.

Comment: I updated the code in the answer above.  You need to wrap your app1 main.py script into a function because flask likes to run functions, not modules.  All of the module level references in the main.py file should still work when you import the function to your flask route.  I also added how you can update the main.py file to run a custom function name of your choosing when you run the file from the command line.  This helps ensure you can still run the script easily from the command line outside the flask context.